# change icon on tabhost android

Tags: java, android, layout, android-tabhost

i want to change icon when click on tabhost

below is the source code

```
    private void setTabs() {
    addTab("Home", TabHome.class, R.drawable.home);
    addTab("Performers", TabPerformers.class, R.drawable.performers);
    addTab("Tickets", TabTickets.class, R.drawable.tickets);
    addTab("Info", TabInfo.class, R.drawable.info);

}

private void addTab(String labelId, Class<?> c, int drawableId) {
    tabHost = getTabHost();
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, c);
    TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("tab" + labelId);

    tabIndicator = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.tab_indicator, getTabWidget(), false);
    icon = (ImageView) tabIndicator.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    icon.setImageResource(drawableId);
    spec.setIndicator(tabIndicator);
    spec.setContent(intent);

    tabHost.addTab(spec);
}
```

i want to change tab's icon when user press tab for that i have used below tabhost event

```
   tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {

            if (tabId.equals("tabHome")) {
```

but could not success

there is also a tab_indicater.xml file but from that only background will be change not icon

below is the xml code

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<!-- Non focused states -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bg_selector" android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true"/>

<!-- Focused states -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bg_selector" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bg_selector" android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true"/>

<!-- Pressed -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bg_selector" android:state_pressed="true" android:state_selected="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_press" android:state_pressed="true"/>
```

below is the screen shot

[image]

when we click on any one tab it's icon should be change like here it must become orange..

can any body help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no straightforward way to change the TabSpec icon. You have to put your icons in the selector drawables.

Comment: but in that also how can u differentiate that this icon is for this tab and that icon is for that tab?

Comment: Simple, use different drawables for different tabs :)

Comment: if u think my question is useful then please upvote my question!